# GPU and CPU needed for multiple chrome browsers running online 2d games

Tags: graphics-cards, processor

I will have 20-30 docker containers each running debian, and a chrome browser running in each of those. Each browser will be playing online slot games.

My current computer doesn't have a good graphics card or processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo processor T6670 clock speed 2.20 GHz, Mobile Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 4500MHD (http://www.toshiba.co.uk/discontinued-products/satellite-pro-c660-16x/)

Just loading a slot machine (or even the william hill homepage) in one chrome browser uses about 40% cpu.

I need to buy a new computer for this. Do I need more cpu or more gpu or both? (gpu for all the animations etc but cpu needed because of multiple docker containers and chrome instances?)

Comment: I'm not asking for technical support. I am asking for "pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task", because I need to buy a new computer to do this. I was just saying what my current computer cpu does to give people more information